# Browserify -i how to ignore full folder

Tags: reactjs, browserify

I'm using browserify in my project, and I want to ignore a whole folder.

I tried :

```
./node_modules/.bin/browserify -i ./react/src/foo/* -s ReactFoo react/src/foo/index.ts --external react --external react-dom > react/dist/bridge.js';
```

but it's not working.

I tried multiple synthax (`react/src/foo/`, `react/src/foo`, `react/src/foo/**`)

For now, the only solution currently working is to ignore all file manually :

```
./node_modules/.bin/browserify -i ./react/src/foo/state/actions.ts -i ./react/src/foo/state/index.ts -i ./react/src/foo/state/reducer.ts -s ReactFoo react/src/foo/index.ts --external react --external react-dom > react/dist/bridge.js';
```